# How to create a 3D falling box demo in famo.us?

Tags: famo.us

I want to create something like this : http://kripken.github.io/ammo.js/examples/new/ammo.html in famo.us.
How do I create a tilted/slanted wall to give the effect of a 2D wall in famo.us?
I am able to create something like this http://hbsand.com/HappyBoxes/ but I want the wall to behave like a 2D wall and not just a line. Perhaps if I can tilt the wall it will give me that effect. I have tried changing the normal of the wall. Also , how to add color and border to the wall ?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?